# The import android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved

Tags: android, aidl

I'm using aidl to answer call automagically, code as following:

```
ITelephony.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("phone"))
    .answerRingingCall();
```

I import ServiceManager.class

```
import android.os.ServiceManager;
```

but there's a problem:The import android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved

How can I make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`android.os.ServiceManager` is a hidden class (i.e., `@hide`) and hidden classes (even if they are public in the Java sense) are removed from android.jar, hence you get the error when you try to import `ServiceManager`.  Hidden classes are those that Google does not want to be part of the documented public API.

Applications using non-public API cannot be compiled easily, there will be different platform versions of this class.

Comment: So there is no way i can use this ServiceManager class in our app..?

Comment: @Ramesh_D yes it is possible, see the reply  from Vinayak below, it's working fine for me

Answer (score 4):

Though it is old one, but no one has answered it yet. Any hidden classes can be used using reflection APIs. Here is an example to acquire a service using Service Manager via reflection APIs:

```
if(mService == null) {
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getMethod("getService", String.class);
                IBinder binder = (IBinder) method.invoke(null, "My_SERVICE_NAME");
                if(binder != null) {
                    mService = IMyService.Stub.asInterface(binder);
                }

                if(mService != null)
                    mIsAcquired = true;

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service is already acquired");
        }
```

Comment: what is IMyService?

Comment: and what is mService? i have uresolved both and not compiled(

Answer (score 1):

As said above these methods work only on System apps or framework apps from Android N on words. 
Still we can code for System app for ServiceManager usage as below using reflection of Android Code

```
  @SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
    public IMyAudioService getService(Context mContext) {
        IMyAudioService mService = null;
        Method method = null;
        try {
            method = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getMethod("getService", String.class);
            IBinder binder = (IBinder) method.invoke(null, "YOUR_METHOD_NAME");
            if (binder != null) {
                mService = IMyAudioService .Stub.asInterface(binder);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mService;
    }
```

Comment: what is create or import IMyAudioService?

Comment: and what is mService? i have uresolved both and not compiled(