# How do I add ITelephony.aidl to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

This is no doubt a very simple question, but unfortunately I have looked around and haven't found a solution.

I would like to import ITelephony.aidl so that I can use

import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

Could someone please give me directions or point me to a tutorial?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can download ITelephony.aidl from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java) and Create   com/android/internal/telephony package in your project src and copy past downloaded ITelephony.AIDL with in com/android/internal/telephony in your package as 
[image: ITelephony.AIDL]

for more information [Blocking Incoming call](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Is it free to use? ITelephony.java? If I have a paid app, can I use this?

Comment: Where do I add aidl files when using gradle / Android Studio? The file structure is a but different than from eclipse: src -> main -> java. I have tried to add the package at all three levels, but it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a public API you have to include it [`yourself from here`.](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/#com/android/internal/telephony) For further reference [`check this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446469/the-import-android-os-servicemanager-cannot-be-resolved).

Comment: Thanks, I have the file, However I'm new to eclipse and now sure how to import file and where it should go. Can you advise?

Comment: just create the package for the file and copy the file into it.

Comment: I have created the directory structure and dropped in the file, However I still get a red x next to .adil file and new to import in my mail class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the ITelephony.java file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java)
2. Create the folder structure src/com/android/internal/telephony and copy the above ITelephony.java file into this folder.
3. Now import the com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony class into your project.

Cheers!!!
Chanaka

Comment: Is it free to use? ITelephony.java? If I have a paid app, can I use this?

Comment: Yes sure. It is a free library. You can use it in any application.