# android.os.ServiceManager not found while building

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am getting following error while building android source, where i have added my custom app which uses android.os.ServiceManager.

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServiceManager
location: package android.os
import android.os.ServiceManager;
```

Why am I facing this error, actually this import can be found in many other app in android source.

I am building the android source as in http://source.android.com/source/building.html
and also followed this post [The import android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446469/the-import-android-os-servicemanager-cannot-be-resolved) answers.

and for more info, I am building in [android root]/packages/app/ directory

Please can anybody help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solved :) Have to remove `LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current` from `Android.mk` file

Comment: Why that so ? any idea

Comment: It's because of ServiceManager is System Api/ hidden api means only system apps can use this API. By removing LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current, we are changing app's SDK version. This is always not a solution ultimately in near future you must have to find an alternative way of this class.  [Google is already restricting hidden apis. https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces ]